# Update radius for circle elements in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I would like to update radius for circle elements in force-directed graph, but when I want to select d3.js object I get error `undefined is not a function`.

**Here is structure of svg element**

[image]

**Click event, which triggers new radius**

```
    $("#resizeN").on("click",function(){

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        var f = d3.select("svg #n" + (i+1).toString().attr("r", function (n){

            return 30 * graph.nodeSizeFactor;  
        }));
    }
});
```

[complete sample](http://jsfiddle.net/90u4sjzm/15/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misplaced parenthesis in your function, it should be like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    var f = d3.select("svg #n" + (i+1).toString()).attr("r", function (n){

        return 30 * graph.nodeSizeFactor;  
    }); // moved it from here to before the .attr
}
```

But without understanding the rest of your code, this doesn't seem like the typical "D3 way" to do things. Is there a common class that you can apply to these nodes and then select them with something like?

```
d3.selectAll('.mycircles').attr('r', function(d) {
    return 30 * graph.nodeSizeFactor; 
});
```

Comment: Parenthesis are right. Yes, I can select nodes with selectAll method. I didn't realize i can apply attr method for more elements at once. I am new in d3.js. Thank you